# ubuntu: rollback all installation to an early date

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

Before this day, I was having this one version of python on my machine (python3.10).

Now after installing anaconda, which didn't work unfortunately, and I uninstalled it, I am left with several python-related files that I don't really have before.
As I start typing python, I see them.

```
$ pyth
python              python3             python3.10          python3.10-config   python3.9           python3-config      python3-futurize    python3-pasteurize  pythran             pythran-config
```

How do I rollback all installation I did on the machine to an early date (say yesterday).

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: I don't know if your O/S has such a feature - it might. You should investigate whether you have something like [timeshift](https://www.makeuseof.com/use-timeshift-backup-and-restore-linux-snapshots/). However, I'm not sure you really need to worry about this. And fwiw I would not install anaconda unless you need to. Much simpler is to install miniconda if the goal is to manage python environments with conda.

Comment: I would be careful with that - unless you installed anaconda with your package manager. Even if you did, you could remove packages you need this way mistake.

Comment: Ubuntu probably has Python installed by default so if you manage to uninstall it you may break stuff. However, but really a programming question so but suitable for this site

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

List of packages installed today:

```
$ grep "2022-10-20.*.install " /var/log/dpkg.log | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -d: -f1
python3-backcall
python3-decorator
python3-parso
python3-jedi
python3-traitlets
python3-matplotlib-inline
python3-pickleshare
python3-wcwidth
...
```

Then uninstalled:

```
$ grep "2022-10-20.*.install " /var/log/dpkg.log | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -d: -f1 | xargs sudo apt-get --yes purge
```

Source: [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/738941/1050909) answer.